# set index and Read Multi-index on columns from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multi-index

I have a .csv that looks like:

```
SiteCode,('Max_Area',1), ('Max_Vol',1)
0003L,3037.1875,13390.319488525391
0009L,7719.25,476.31626510620117
```

The first column is the desired index and the following tuples are my desired column names. When I read the csv in like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",index_col=0)
```

I get a data frame that looks like:

```
          (Max_Area            1)   (Max_Vol         1)
SiteCode                                                                
0003L     3037.1875  13390.319489  NaN  NaN       
0009L     7719.2500    476.316265  NaN  NaN
```

I want a dataframe that looks like:

```
SiteCode  (Max_Area,1)   (Max_Vol,1)                       
0003L     3037.1875  13390.319489    
0009L     7719.2500    476.316265
```

Is it possible to read a csv with comma delimited tuples as a header?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can explicitly pass in the column names you want to use and skip the header row:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", 
                 names=['SiteCode', '(Max_Area, 1)', '(Max_Vol, 1)'],
                 skiprows=1, 
                 index_col=0)

df

          (Max_Area,1)   (Max_Vol,1)
SiteCode                         
0003L     3037.1875      13390.319489    
0009L     7719.2500        476.316265
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the first line, extract the column names and supply this information to the csv reader:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    header = f.readline()[:-1]

pattern = re.compile(r"(?:[^,(]|\([^)]*\))+")
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", names = pattern.findall(header), skiprows = 1)
#output
  SiteCode  ('Max_Area',1)  ('Max_Vol',1)
0    0003L       3037.1875   13390.319489
1    0009L       7719.2500     476.316265
```